# Trouble implementing inappbrowser with PhoneGap Build

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am working on a web app, and am building it with HTML, CSS and Javascript. I am not using PhoneGap, but am using PhoneGap Build to compile my app.

I have added `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />` [as seen here](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1169) to my config.xml file

However, I cannot get the plugin to work. This is my first web app, so I don't know if I need also install PhoneGap to make this work?

Comment: No, it works fine in PGB - I've used it lots of times before. My advice is to put in some logging code and test it with Chrome Inspect. This is likely a simple syntax error,

Comment: @Stephen What error you are getting. You just have to write  window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes'); to use plugin.

Comment: @Suhas I'm not getting an error, nothing happens. Is there a place I can look for error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following scripts to my index.html file in the head before any other script and it worked.

NOTE: These scripts are not part of my project structure, and are loaded dynamically through PhoneGap Build. I just needed to reference them.

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="inappbrowser.js"></script>
```